# Monitor only shows white screen

Tags: display, white-screen

My monitor only displays a white screen when turned on. No boot image is shown, nor is the OSD working. Not sure what the issue is? It was working and now it isn't. Computer works just fine with another monitor.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've provided, it sounds like your monitor has failed. There are a couple of points to consider though:

1. Are you using the same cable between the potentially faulty monitor and your other monitor? If not and it's possible to do so, use the same cable for each to eliminate this being the problem.
2. Are you using the same port between the potentially faulty monitor and your other monitor? If not, it's possible something is wrong with the output to that port, which is possible if they are different technologies (VGA vs DVI vs Display Port vs HDMI).

If you are using the same cable, in the same port, but with a different monitor, and that scenario works, then your original monitor has failed. There isn't a viable repair strategy for monitors, parts are hard to source and new monitors aren't typically too expensive.

Comment: Cabling and port seem unlikely points of failure in this case since the OSD isn't working. At least in traditional terminology, that's built into the monitor itself (the monitor overlaying its On Screen Display over the image provided by the computer).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Agreed, but I didn't want to assume anything as some monitors won't let you open the OSD without an input source and dodgy cabling could cause an unpredictable result. Figured it would be best to state some fairly quick diagnostics to be certain. I'm quite confident the monitor has failed either way.